# Jerarquizar layouts

Tags: android, xml, layout

Quiero organizar la pantalla de una actividad de esta forma:

[image: Planteamiento de la idea]

Hasta el momento tengo esto pero se me solapan todos los layouts empezando desde arriba uno encima de otro:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/saldo"
        android:textColor="@color/letra"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</TableLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: te queda algo [asi](https://i.imgur.com/dFN7XrA.png)?

Comment: eso es, el primer layout he conseguido que se ajuste tal y como quiero en cambio los demás en vez de empezar donde termina el layout superior empiezan donde empieza el primero :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<sub>Nota: como he visto que en tu pregunta anterior te recomendaban el uso de  `RelativeLayout` y en ésta lo incluyes, no te recomendaré el uso de otro como el  `LinearLayout`</sub>

---

Has de usar `android:layout_below= android:id` donde el ID es el del elemento superior.

En tu imagen, en el elemento Azul, pondrias `android:layout_below="@+id/cuadradoVerde"` y asi con el resto.

En esta documentación tienes un [ejemplo](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html?hl=es-419#Example)

Comment: Gracias se agradece la ayuda ;D

Comment: Como comentas @lois6b, de acuerdo a su pregunta anterior y esta, la mejor solución es esta que comentas definitivamente.

Comment: @Jorgesys gracias ^^, pero bueno, es cosa del autor. heheh

Answer (score 3):

Antes que nada aquí te dejo un [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_user_interface_layouts.htm) de algunos de los Layouts de Android.

Si quieres agregar elementos de forma en que vayan quedando uno debajo del otro utiliza un `LinearLayout` con orientación vertical:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/background"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/saldoLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/saldoTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/saldo"
        android:textColor="@color/letra"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
</LinearLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Si lo que quieres es establecer jerarquías en un `RelativeLayout` utiliza:

**Atributos XML**

```
android:layout_above
```

Posiciona el borde inferior de este punto de vista por encima de la vista de anclaje ID dado.

```
android:layout_alignBaseline
```

Posiciona a la base de este punto de vista sobre la línea de base de la opinión de anclaje ID dado.

```
android:layout_alignBottom
```

Hace que el borde inferior de este punto de vista coincide con el borde inferior de la vista de anclaje ID dado.

```
android:layout_alignEnd
```

Hace que el borde extremo de este punto de vista coincide con el borde extremo de la vista de anclaje ID dado.

```
android:layout_alignLeft
```

Hace que el borde izquierdo de este punto de vista coincide con el borde izquierdo de la vista del ancla Identificación dado.

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom
```

Si es verdad, hace que el borde inferior de este punto de vista coincide con el borde inferior de la matriz.

```
android:layout_alignParentEnd
```

Si es verdad, hace que el borde extremo de este punto de vista coincide con el borde extremo de la matriz.

```
android:layout_alignParentLeft
```

Si es verdad, hace que el borde izquierdo de este punto de vista coincide con el borde izquierdo de la matriz.

```
android:layout_alignParentRight
```

Si es verdad, hace que el borde derecho de este punto de vista coincide con el borde derecho de la matriz.

```
android:layout_alignParentStart
```

Si es verdad, hace que el borde de inicio de este punto de vista coincide con el borde de inicio de los padres.

```
android:layout_alignParentTop
```

Si es verdad, hace que el borde superior de este punto de vista coincide con el borde superior de la matriz.

```
android:layout_alignRight
```

Hace que el borde derecho de este punto de vista coincide con el borde derecho de la vista del ancla Identificación dado.

```
android:layout_alignStart
```

Hace que el borde de inicio de este punto de vista coincide con el borde de inicio de la vista del ancla Identificación dado.

```
android:layout_alignTop
```

Hace que el borde superior de este punto de vista coincide con el borde superior de la vista del ancla Identificación dado.

```
android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing
```

Si es verdadero, el padre será usado como el ancla cuando el ancla no se puede encontrar para layout_toLeftOf, layout_toRightOf, etc.

```
android:layout_below
```

Posiciona el borde superior de este punto de vista debajo de la vista de anclaje ID dado.

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal
```

Si esto es cierto, se centra este niño horizontalmente dentro de su matriz.

```
android:layout_centerInParent
```

Si esto es cierto, se centra este niño horizontal y verticalmente dentro de su matriz.

```
android:layout_centerVertical
```

Si esto es cierto, se centra este niño verticalmente dentro de su matriz.

```
android:layout_toEndOf
```

Posiciona el borde de inicio de este punto de vista hasta el final de la vista del ancla Identificación dado.

```
android:layout_toLeftOf
```

Posiciona el borde derecho de este punto de vista a la izquierda de la vista del ancla Identificación dado.

```
android:layout_toRightOf
```

Posiciona el borde izquierdo de este punto de vista a la derecha de la vista de anclaje ID dado.

```
android:layout_toStartOf
```

Posiciona el borde extremo de esta vista para el inicio de la vista del ancla Identificación dado.

Puedes leerte la documentación de los diferentes Layouts [aqui](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) para que aprendas cual usar en cualquier caso de diseño.

Comment: Mi idea es la de según cada cajetin de color que he adjuntado en la foto emplear un layout ya que quiero que tenga distintas orientaciones. Es decir en el primer cajetin verde aparecera un textview, en el cajetin azul un TableLayout en el siguiente un linearLayout. Que me recomiendas meter todo en un linear layout?

Comment: En realidad no es necesario utilizar TableLayouts. Puedes crear más LinearLayouts o incluso Relatives dentro de tu LinearLayout padre. Todo depende de cómo se te haga mas cómodo y lo que quieras hacer.

Comment: Pero debes saber como utilizas las propiedades de los Layouts, para definir el tamaño, margenes, tamaño de los items que estarán dentro de esos Layouts hijos y así. Leete bien la documentación para implementar diseños y practica. Con el tiempo aprenderás, tambien debes aprender a utilizar las propiedades de los layouts. ejemplo: diferencia entre layout_gravity y gravity, layout_margin y margin etc...

Comment: Le pegaré una leída ahora en cuanto pueda. Mi idea es hacer el gui principal de mi juego/aplicación. Donde en el primer cajetín aparecería el saldo que dispone, en El Segundo cajetín dos layouts donde aparecería el valor mayor y menor de los valores de bolsa. El tercer cajetín una lista de botonos con todas las entidades con las que quiero operar y abajo tres botones donde poder cambiar de menu.

Comment: "se centra este niño verticalmente"...un niño?  ⤜(ʘ_ʘ)⤏